# c# DateTime.ParseExact exception in specific date "dd/MM/yy"

Tags: c#, .net

my code look like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

when the date is "31/11/10" the exception:

```
System.FormatException: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.
```

is thrown.

in the cases "31/10/10" or "31/12/10" it's working fine, why it's happening?

Comment: There are only 30 days in November.

Comment: Who else has just ran through the nursery rhyme?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The month november only has 30 days so the 31 november does not exist.

Comment: Oh i didn't check it, it's a user input

Answer (score 1):

There are only 30 days in the November month